# html5 canvas sprite sheet random rows/columns

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, sprite-sheet

At the moment the code chooses from one row of images from the sprite sheet and displays it going from left to right of the screen, what I'd like to do is select random images like its doing but from a different row, for example I have 3 rows with 1 row of 3 different coloured asteroids 32 by 32, 2nd row 3 different coloured 64 by 64 and final row 3 different coloured 128 by 128. How would I random the rows to show different sizes as well as colours

This is the current code, any help would be fantastic.

```
function Enemy() {
this.srcX = 0;
this.srcY = 528;
this.width = 32;
this.height = 33;
this.previousSpeed = 0;
this.speed = 2;
this.acceleration = 0.005;
this.imageNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
this.drawX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + gameWidth;
this.drawY = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameHeight);
this.collisionPointX = this.drawX + this.width;
this.collisionPointY = this.drawY + this.height;    
}

Enemy.prototype.draw = function () {
this.drawX -= this.speed;
ctxEnemy.drawImage(imgSprite,this.srcX+this.imageNumber*this.width,this.srcY,this.width,this.height,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.width,this.height);
this.checkEscaped();
};

Enemy.prototype.assignValues = function() {

}

Enemy.prototype.checkEscaped = function () {
if (this.drawX + this.width <= 0) {
    this.recycleEnemy();
}
};

Enemy.prototype.recycleEnemy = function () {
this.drawX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + gameWidth;
this.drawY = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameHeight);
};

function clearCtxEnemy() {
ctxEnemy.clearRect(0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an object to store all your asteroids.  Then use a random number as a key to get a random asteroid.

```
var min = 1;
var max = 9;
var key = Math.floor(Math.random() * max ) + min;

var asteroids = {
    1 :{
        'width' : 64,
        'height' : 64,
        'colour' : 'blue'
    },
    2 : {
        'width' : 64,
        'height' : 64,
        'colour' : 'red'
    },

    //repeat until the last one....

    9 : {
        'width' : 128,
        'height' : 128,
        'colour' : 'green'
    }
};


console.log( asteroids[key]['colour'] );
console.log( asteroids[key]['width'] );
console.log( asteroids[key]['height'] );
```

Comment: Would I include this in the same js file?

Comment: Would I need to add anything else into the file?

Comment: Most likely, yes.  This is just an example of how to organize all your asteroids so you can access a random one.

Comment: Possibly, the best way to find out is to try it.